# Selenium chrome webdriver not able to locate elements in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a python program and it needs to be able to send a google hangouts message. I initially tried an API but found out these are only available for hangouts chat. So now I am trying `selenium webdriver`. But I've run into a problem while trying to open a chat; the program gives me an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"CSS selector","selector":"div.gS5QBe.R8jgRe"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://hangouts.google.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("gb_70").click()
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
elem.send_keys("my_username")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(3)
pas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.whsOnd")
pas.send_keys("my_password")
pas.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(10)
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.gS5QBe.R8jgRe")
```

I have tried looking online but I cannot find a solution. Here is the [website](https://hangouts.google.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be lot of iframe in the page. Create locator for specific iframe which the element holds. I see the second iframe has new message button.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//iframe)[2]"))
```

But i will recommend you to use [Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) provided by google

Comment: Does the frame not have a name or other distinguishing feature? Using indices is going to be fragile because if they update the page and the index changes, your test will fail.